# PHP not including variables

Tags: php

I have a `connection.php` and `settings.php`.

**connection.php:**

```
<?php

require_once("settings.php");

$conn = oci_connect($db_user, $db_pass, $db_ip/$db);
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

?>
```

**settings.php:**

```
<?

$db_ip = '192.168.1.1';
$db = 'A.world';
$db_user = 'user';
$db_pass = 'pass';

?>
```

The connection here doesn't work, but if I replace the variables with their strings then the connection works. What is going wrong here? Also should I be using `include`, `include_once`, or `require_once`?

Comment: `$db_ip/$db` ?!? WTF.... is that simply a typo here, or do you actually have that in your code? Try `$db_ip.'/'.$db`

Comment: @MarkBaker i was thinking the same ... what exactly are you trying to archive with that?

Comment: From the PHP website `$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');`.

Comment: When not a quoted string, `/` is the division operator in PHP: `$db_ip/$db` means value of $db_ip divided by value of $db

Comment: @user2656114 you need a string there, you are giving 2 variables and a slash. The result is not a string anymore and therefore false. Second Rikudo posted how its actually done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want `"{$db_ip}/{$db}"` Note the quotes.